# Android ListView has a empty line at the top

Tags: android, listview

Whatever I set ListView attribute,it has a empty line at the top,I can't get rid of,I find many methods,but can't figure it out.My environment is in Android 4.1,so please help,thanks in advance.

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17px" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSource"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10px" />

<com.ibelieve.news.View.XListView
    android:id="@+id/lvArray"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
</com.ibelieve.news.View.XListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code file:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_list);
    listview = (XListView) findViewById(R.id.lvArray);

    ArrayList<News> newslist = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("newslist");
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    String[] result = new String[newslist.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < newslist.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("title", newslist.get(i).Title);
            map.put("source", newslist.get(i).Source + " " + newslist.get(i).Time);
            list.add(map);
        }
    }
    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(NewsListActivity.this, list, R.layout.news_list, new String[] { "title", "source" }, new int[] { R.id.tvTitle, R.id.tvSource });
    listview.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Please, don't use **px** for textSizes. Use **sp**, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using your activity's resource as an item for list view. Move

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17px" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSource"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10px" />
```

To a new resource files and use that resource file in new SimpleAdapter(...) parameters

edit: oh and those "empty lines" are those textviews that you added in your activity's resources. And each your listview item contains an empty listview...ception

Comment: I move xml above to list_item.xml，it works for me,Thanks very much,its awesome! Change simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(NewsListActivity.this, list, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "title", "source" }, new int[] { R.id.tvTitle, R.id.tvSource });